# Dashes (or strippled line, dashed) in tabbar for emacs with X

Tags: buffers, customize, gui-emacs, tabbar

I'm trying to go full minimalist over here... But I can't figure out how to remove the strippled line next to "untitled".
I'd like it to be nothing at all.

The customizations I've done so far for tabbar in my .emacs is under the image.

The strippled line does not appear when tabbar is uncustomized.
It appears when `'(tabbar-background-color "color-237")` is set.

[image]

```
;; Loads tabbar and customizations
(tabbar-mode 1)
(setq tabbar-use-images nil)
(setq tabbar-buffer-groups-function(lambda() (list "All Buffers")))
(defun buffer-groups()
  (list (cond ((string-equal "*" (substring (buffer-name) 0 1)) "emacs")
              ((eq major-mode 'dired-mode) "emacs") (t "user"))))
(setq tabbar-buffer-groups-function 'buffer-groups)
```

and some from customize-group:

```
'(tabbar-background-color "color-237")
'(tabbar-buffer-home-button (quote (("") "")))
'(tabbar-home-button (quote (("") "")))
'(tabbar-scroll-left-button (quote (("") "")))
'(tabbar-scroll-right-button (quote (("") "")))
'(tabbar-separator (quote (2)

'(tabbar-button ((t nil)))
'(tabbar-default ((t (:background "color-237" :foreground "color-250"))))
'(tabbar-highlight ((t nil)))
'(tabbar-modified ((t (:inherit tabbar-default :foreground "#87D700"))))
'(tabbar-selected ((t (:inherit tabbar-default :foreground "#1EE8FF"))))
'(tabbar-selected-modified ((t (:inherit tabbar-default :foreground "#1EE8FF"))))
'(tabbar-unselected ((t (:inherit tabbar-default))))
```

Comment: The default behavior of `tabbar.el` version 2.0 -- https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/tabbar -- does *not* generate a view as depicted in your picture.  So, whatever you are doing, it is much different than the stock `tabbar.el` library.  Please provide more details (code) and/or a link to whatever code you are using to create the `header-line-format` -- i.e., `untitled --------------------`.

Comment: This question risks being closed as unclear. You need to provide a *lot* more specifics about what you are doing. Provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). Say what you see at each significant step, and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: @lawlist added my customizations so far below the image :)

Comment: Did a quick "when does the strippled line appear" by commenting out one by one customization. Seems like one "'(tabbar-background-color "color-237")" is set, the line appears.

Comment: So you've resolved the issue, then -- just pick a valid color instead?

Comment: @lawlist ...wow, that sure made me feel stupid. You're completely right, a correct color made it go away. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value inside 
`'(tabbar-background-color "color-237")` was invalid.
Changed it to `'(tabbar-background-color "#3A3A3A")` - and it worked.